# How to overcome android twitter authentication exception (401)?

Tags: android, authentication, twitter, twitter4j

I integrated  twitter in my app and published it. But now there is an issue with twitter.
While debugging i got the following exception in logcat

> 06-24 11:23:49.286: W/System.err(27752): 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
>   06-24 11:23:49.286: W/System.err(27752): Failed to validate oauth signature and token
>   06-24 11:23:49.286: W/System.err(27752): Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
>   06-24 11:23:49.286: W/System.err(27752):    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=10f5ada3 or
>   06-24 11:23:49.286: W/System.err(27752):    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0276a2ab
>   06-24 11:23:49.286: W/System.err(27752): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[10f5ada3-0276a2ab], statusCode=401, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.5}
>   06-24 11:23:49.286: W/System.err(27752):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:162)
>   06-24 11:23:49.286: W/System.err(27752):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
>   06-24 11:23:49.286: W/System.err(27752):    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:98)
>   06-24 11:23:49.286: W/System.err(27752):    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:122)
>   06-24 11:23:49.286: W/System.err(27752):    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:104)
>   06-24 11:23:49.286: W/System.err(27752):    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:298)

I rechecked my consumer key and consumer secret, they are same. Some links proposes regenerate key and then try,but is there any way to correct that without any change in code?Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you please provide the code!

Answer (score 0):

Check your device **time and date** and also your Oauth key.It will helps you to handle the twitter exception.